# Finding a "Count Sequence"

Tags: algorithm, haskell

Given a list of integers `xs`, let:

```
count :: [Integer] -> Integer -> Integer
count xs n = length . filter (==n) $ xs
```

count the number of times the integer `n` occurs in the list.

Now, given a "list" (some sort of array of integers, can be something besides a List) of length `n`, write a function

```
countSequence :: [Integer] -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
countSequence xs n m = [count xs x | x <- [0..m]]
```

that outputs the "list of counts" (0th index contains number of times 0 occurs in the list, 1st index contains number of times 1 occurs in the list, etc) **that has time compleity o(m*n)**

The above implementation I've given has complexity O(m*n).  In Python (which I'm more familiar with), it's easy to do this in O(m + n) time --- iterate through the list, and each element increment a counter in some other list, which is initialized to be all zeros and length (m+1).

How could I get a better implementation in Haskell?  I'd prefer if it wasn't some trivial way to implement the Python solution (such as adding another input to the function to keep the "list of counts" in and then interating through it).

Comment: You don't use `n` in countSequence, or am i missing the obvious?

Comment: I don't really see a place that using n gains me anything (I didn't make this problem, I was given it).  As n = length xs, unless I can get a solution faster than O(n) I can always just compute it first if it's needed.  That being said, if it ends up being useful for something I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: @Mark, You could do the same solution as python, but construct a `Data.Map` with the necessary counts, that would get you to O(m log m). 
This also might be a good fit for [data-inttrie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-inttrie), which would be O(m log M) (where M is the largest number in the list).

Comment: @luqui I'm really interested in solutions that _aren't_ just porting the Python one.  I'm mostly just curious what an efficient functional solution to a problem like this is, and said o(n*m) because I wanted one more efficient than the "easy" one I found.

Comment: @luqui Also, do you have a reference for time complexities of `data-inttrie`?

Comment: Anything you can do in O(n) with an impure algorithm can be done in at worst O(n log n) with a pure algorithm (by, e.g., replacing an array with a binary tree) ([source](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall03/cs528/handouts/Pure%20Versus%20Impure%20LISP.pdf)). In this case, I would suggest an IntMap. You could also achieve O(n + m) with a mutable vector (in `ST` or `IO`) and a direct port of the python algorithm.

Comment: Can you count the frequencies of all occurrences rather than just the ones in `[0..m]`? If so, `foldl' (\a b -> IM.insertWith (+) b 1 a) IM.empty` is reasonable (where `IM` is `Data.IntMap`). I assume that you want to use machine integers (so `Int`, not `Integer`) since you're trying to compare with a python implementation.

Comment: I'll also note that `Data.IntMap.insertWith` is `O(min(n, 64))` (or 32 for 32-bit machine ints) in the number of elements so it quickly becomes linear for most use cases.

Comment: I'll also also note that if you do want to count only items `[0..m]` then you can just filter the list first to only include those items without changing the asymptotics.

Comment: I'll also also also note that the type of `countSequence` is incorrect. A list comprehension must give a list. I think that's it.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Immutable arrays offer the right operation as well (no need for `IO` or `ST`), and then you don't need to pfaff about with the extra worries about whether the tree shape of `IntMap` incurs an extra log-cost or not (it has always struck me as a bit disingenuous to ignore the log factor just because `Int`s are constant-width).

Comment: Your `countSequence` function doesn't type check in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

In `O(n+m)` (sort of, I think, maybe):

```
import Data.Ix (inRange)
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as IM

countSequence m =
  foldl' count IM.empty . filter (inRange (0,m))
    where count a b = IM.insertWith (+) b 1 a
```

gives

```
> countSequence 2 [1,2,3,1,2,-1]
fromList [(1,2),(2,2)]
```

I haven't used `n` because you also didn't use `n` and I'm not sure what it's supposed to be. I also moved the list to the last argument to put it in a position to be eta reduced.

Comment: This also has the advantage of not requiring the bounds to be known up front if you remove the `filter` and the `m` argument.

Comment: To produce the same output as the original function, where `countSequence m xs !! i == count xs i` for all `i` in `[0..m]`, you can make the initial accumulator `IntMap.fromList [(x, 0) | x <- [0..m]]` and add `IntMap.elems` to the composition. Or you can leave it as an `IntMap` and use `IntMap.findWithDefault 0`, in which case it’s fine to start with `IntMap.empty` (or `mempty`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use your Python intuition -- iterate through the one list and increment a counter in another list. Here's an implementation with O(n+m) runtime:

```
import Data.Array
countSequence xs m = accumArray (+) 0 (0,m) [(x, 1) | x <- xs, inRange (0,m) x]
```

(This use case is even the motivating example for the existence of `accumArray` in the documentation!) In ghci:

```
> countSequence ([1..5] ++ [1,3..5] ++ [1,4..5] ++ [1,5]) 3
array (0,3) [(0,0),(1,4),(2,1),(3,2)]
```

Comment: Someone should benchmark our answers in their copious free time.

Comment: Also, what is the asymptotic time of `accumArray`? The docs don't give it.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs The docs don't say, but the main drivers are allocating and initializing an array of the appropriate size (O(m)) and running the given function once for each element in the input list (O(n)). It's a really thin wrapper around your proposed solution from the comments: allocating a mutable array and freezing it once you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I guess using `Data.IntMap` would be as efficient as it gets for this job. One `foldr` pass is done to establish the `IntMap` (`cm`) and a `map` to construct a new list holding the counts of elements at corresponding positions.

```
import qualified Data.IntMap.Lazy as IM

countSequence :: [Int] -> [Int]
countSequence xs = map (\x -> let cm = foldr (\x m -> IM.alter (\mx -> if mx == Nothing then Just 1 else fmap (+1) mx) x m) IM.empty xs
                              in IM.findWithDefault 0 x cm) xs

*Main> countSequence [1,2,5,1,3,7,8,5,6,4,1,2,3,7,9,3,4,8]
[3,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,1,2,3,2,3,2,1,3,2,2]
*Main> countSequence [4,5,4]
[2,1,2]
*Main> *Main> countSequence [9,8,7,6,5]
[1,1,1,1,1]
```